# Register new user Openfire server return bad-request stanzas

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I'm trying to register new user using aSmack 4 using this code :

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(Constant.XMPP_HOST, Constant.XMPP_PORT);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

String user ="bear";
String pass = "123";
String email = "bear@bear.com";
HashMap<String,String> attr = new HashMap<String, String>();
attr.put("username",user);
attr.put("password",pass);
attr.put("email", email);
if(conn2!=null) {

Registration reg = new Registration();
reg.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
reg.setTo(conn2.getServiceName());
reg.setAttributes(attr);
PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(
        reg.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
PacketCollector collector = conn2 .createPacketCollector(filter);
try {
    conn2.sendPacket(reg);
} catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
IQ result = (IQ) collector.nextResult(SmackConfiguration
        .getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
System.out.println(result);
collector.cancel();
```

But Openfire server return this packet and I do not know what it mean .

```
<iq id='XILKN-9' to='pc-pc/b529612d' from='192.168.21.107' type='error'>
      <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
          <password>123</password>
          <email>bear@bear.com</email>
          <username>bear</username>
     </query>
     <error type="modify">
          <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

WHat is the problem ? I'm using OpenFire 3.9.3 and aSmack 4.0.7 .

Comment: buddy how did you solve the problem? I got the same problem here..

Comment: me too have the same problem... It works when trying create with an authenticated connection of other user to new user, but not when trying with anonymous connection... :(

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but hope it helps someone.
In your connection configuration , make sure you `setServiceName` correctly. I.e `config.setServiceName(Name of your service);`